# Windows WMI get a snapshot EnabledState

Tags: windows, hyper-v, wmi, snapshot, winrm

I am trying to get the EnabledState of a virtual machine snapshot using WMI. That is I try to get the EnabledState that was current for the virtual machine when the snapshot was taken.

So far I know how to list all snapshots of the machine. For that I use:

```
winrm e wmi/root/virtualization/* -filter:"select * from Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData where SettingType = 5"
```

This gives a lot of information about the snapshots but it does not give me the Enabled state of the virtual machine. Any ideas how can I get that?